# Javascript Odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-12

i'm trying to learn the javascript of odoo ,and as you all know there are very few documentation about it
First i could finally create a view template with its client action ,add a button to excute a code from js
JS :

```
odoo.define('js_client_view.ClientReportWidget', function (require) {
'use strict';

    console.log("module loaded");

    var AbstractAction = require('web.AbstractAction');
    var Widget = require('web.Widget');
    var core = require('web.core');
    require('web.dom_ready');
    var ajax = require('web.ajax');

    var button = $('#mybutton');


    var JsClientView = Widget.extend({
        //contentTemplate: 'UploadDocumentMainMenu',
        template: 'JsClientView',

        events: {
            'click .mybutton': '_onButton',
    
        },

        init: function(){
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            data =ajax.jsonRpc('/get_clients', 'call', {}).then(function(data) {
                console.log("in data")
                console.log(data)
                return data
            });
            console.log(data)
        },
        _onButton: function(event) {
            console.log("in On Button");
            console.log(event);
            ajax.jsonRpc('/get_clients', 'call', {}).then(function(data) {
                console.log("in data")
                console.log(data)
            });
        },


    });

    core.action_registry.add('js_client_view', JsClientView);
    return JsClientView;

});
```

My template :

```
<templates xml:space="preserve" >
    <t t-name="JsClientView" >
                    <div class="container o_mrp_bom_report_page">
            <span class="o_report_heading text-left">
                <br/>
                <button type="button" class= "btn btn-secondary mybutton" 
                >Test </button>

                <h1>Relevé de compte client</h1>
                <strong>
                    <t >
                        <span>Tous les client</span>
                    </t>
                  
                </strong>
            </span>
        
    </t>

</templates>
```

And the controller that return info to the button function:

```
class OdooControllers(http.Controller):
    @http.route(['/get_clients'], type='json',auth='public', website=True)
    def get_clients(self, **kw):
        clients = http.request.env['hr.employee'].sudo().search([('department_id', '=',5)], limit=6)
        c = []
        for client in clients:
            n = {
                'name': client.name,
                'id': client.id,
                'certificate': client.certificate,

            }
            c.append(n)
        return c
```

Now i want to send this information to the template and display it
How can i do that !

Comment: Can't decide, because i don't have an answer yet. But it might seem that way, when reading the whole question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Odoo JS` is the frontend of odoo. As such you cannot edit the template itself since you are not in the backend. Odoo is using a classical **client-server architecture** therefore, your JS is seperated from the server.

However you can edit the entire `DOM` tree by accessing normal `jquery` and `JS` features. You could do something like this:

Add a placeholder `div` somewhere:

```html
<div id ="content">
</div>
```

Fill that `div` with data.

```
// On click find that div and inject content into it
ajax.jsonRpc('/get_clients', 'call', {}).then(function(data) {
    $("#content").html("<p>Hello World<p/>");
    // Later fill the content with data
});
```

You could probably use no `JS` at all for your example but as far as I understood, your goal is to specifically use `JS` to display that data for practice. So that's how you would inject data from the server into the `DOM` by using `JS`.

Comment: thank you it's very helpfull , in your case you just added an Html content ,i can do that for more content like for example  name , certificate and id that i got from the controller